# Smoothly rotating a canvas element on setInterval()

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I am trying to replicate this effect: http://codepen.io/kenjiSpecial/pen/enrbq

I have a Segment class:

```
function Segment (x, y, length) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.color = '#fff';
}
```

I use it to fill the screen with vertical lines (made out of segments) and then rotate each of them by 45deg clockwise using this function and a setInterval:

```
function drawSegments(segment) {
    segment.rotation = angle;
    segment.draw(ctx);
}

setInterval(function(){
    angle += 45 * Math.PI / 180;
}, 800);
```

It works (i.e. the lines are rotated on each 800ms) but there is no animation between the transitions.. I tried somethig like this, but unfortunately it doesn't work...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    angle += i * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

So, the problem is - how to animate each rotation of the segments?

Here is the link to the live demo: http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/KEGzJ

Comment: And one additional question: how do I set up a transform origin for the segments? Right now, they are rotated around x and y, but I want them to rotate around their middle point. So something like x, y + segment.length / 2

Comment: The midpoint of the line is: `var x=(x0+x1)/2; var y=(y0+y1)/2;` BTW, The link to the effect you're desiring is both rotating and translating.  The effect takes one side of a rectangle and rotates + moves it counterclockwise until it becomes the next side of the same rectangle.